# How to set two or more buttons side by side to fill width of screen at bottom of the layout (not like a sticky menu)?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to set two or more buttons side by side at the bottom of the screen, I do know that in LinearLayout you can set buttons side by side by using **android:layout_weight**
and i know that I can set the buttons at the bottom of the screen by using relative layout, but I cant seem to do both at the same time for the same buttons! is that possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#0B333F"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp" >

            <!-- <LinearLayout -->
            <!-- android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
            <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
            <!-- android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" -->
            <!-- android:layout_marginTop="5dp" -->
            <!-- android:paddingLeft="5dp" -->
            <!-- android:paddingRight="5dp" > -->


            <!-- android:layout_weight="1" -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="#F0BF00"
                android:text="@string/save"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="#F0BF00"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <!-- </LinearLayout> -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

As you can see in the commented part, I did try both but cant seem to get it to work! Please help.

FYI

I don't want a sticky menu; in small screens there will be a scroll so this will not affect small screens since it is already at he bottom, but big screens that will not need to scroll I want the buttons at the bottom

Comment: Add a `RelativeLayout`,inside that add another `LinearLayout` and then add your buttons as you said earlier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to do it by adding

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

as PiYusH GuPtA suggested to the **LinearLayout** that contains the buttons, but I also needed to change that **LinearLayout** layout from

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F0BF00"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F0BF00"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to your view at bottom you have to just set

```
  android:gravity="bottom"
```

to your `LinearLayout`.

UPDATE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="#0B333F"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <!-- <LinearLayout -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" -->
        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="5dp" -->
        <!-- android:paddingLeft="5dp" -->
        <!-- android:paddingRight="5dp" > -->


        <!-- android:layout_weight="1" -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#F0BF00"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="#F0BF00"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!-- </LinearLayout> -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: So would you want to use that in ScrollView there is two layout one is at bottom and another is on top of bottom layout??

Comment: that did work but after I set **android:layout_height="fill_parent"** to the **LinearLayout** that contains the buttons

Comment: yes man, I posted my result, the **android:gravity="bottom"** was 75% of the answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#F0BF00"
            android:text="save"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="#F0BF00"
            android:text="cancel"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your buttons to always be visible on the screen and your buttons centered at the bottom, move your ScrollView like in the following. If you want your buttons to fill the bottom line or be placed relative to the edges, then the bottom LinearLayout can be removed and a couple of alignment attributes set on the buttons instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#0B333F"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            .....
            .....
            .....
            .....
            .....

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F0BF00"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="#F0BF00"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: don't want them stinking at the bottom, I want the user to finish filling the form then hit the save or cancel button, otherwise he might not fill all the form inputs. but in some big screens this will not be an issue and the from will not have a scroll in that case i want them at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I think here are a good solution for you

```
<RelativeLayout > 
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button />
        <Button />
     </LinearLayout>
     <ScrollView 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomLayout">
      </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

They are only nested layout structure so you need add more attribute that you want. Please let me know the result asap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the buttons always at the bottom of the content, not always visible on the screen, and to fill the bottom row of the screen, you can do the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#0B333F"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        ........
        ........
        ........
        ........
        ........
        ........

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#F0BF00"
                android:text="@string/save"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="#F0BF00"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```